# How to solve this limit $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{5-x}-2}{\sqrt{10-x}-3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Compute $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{5-x}-2}{\sqrt{10-x}-3}$$

Can some one help me to solve this please? I tried many ways but it leads me always to $0/0$.

Comment: Is the use of l'Hopital allowed?

Comment: I'd probably l'Hospital the hell out of it.

Comment: Divide the top and bottom by $x-1.$  Then you can avoid L'Hopital.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiplying it by $\frac{\sqrt{10-x}+3}{\sqrt{10-x}+3}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{5-x}+2}{\sqrt{5-x}+2}\ (=1)$ will help.

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{5-x}-2}{\sqrt{10-x}-3}&=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\color{red}{\sqrt{5-x}-2}}{\color{blue}{\sqrt{10-x}-3}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{10-x}+3}{\color{blue}{\sqrt{10-x}+3}}\cdot\frac{\color{red}{\sqrt{5-x}+2}}{\sqrt{5-x}+2}\\&=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\color{red}{((5-x)-4)}\cdot(\sqrt{10-x}+3)}{\color{blue}{((10-x)-9)}\cdot(\sqrt{5-x}+2)}\\&=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{(1-x)(\sqrt{10-x}+3)}{(1-x)(\sqrt{5-x}+2)}\\&=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{10-x}+3}{\sqrt{5-x}+2}\\&=\frac{\sqrt{9}+3}{\sqrt 4+2}\\&=\frac 32\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Using l'Hopital:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{5-x}-2}{\sqrt{10-x}-3} = \lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{5-x}-2)}{\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{10-x}-3)}=\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{5-x}}}{-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{10-x}}}$$

Last function is continuous around $x=1$, therefore we can just fill it in to get $\frac{-\frac{1}{4}}{-\frac{1}{6}}=\frac{6}{4}=\frac{3}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding l'Hopital (always a good idea if you can): Let $f(x)= \sqrt {5-x}, g(x) = \sqrt {10-x}.$ The expression equals

$$\frac{(f(x)- f(1))/(x-1) }{(g(x) - g(1))/(x-1)} \to \frac{f'(1)}{g'(1)}$$

simply from the definition of the derivative. The latter equals $3/2.$